# I keep receiving java.awt.print.PrinterException: Paper's imageable height is too small

Tags: java, swing, printing

I'm trying to print out a jpanel and it's components to a 4X2 label, I'm new to java and I'm not sure were to go next on how to adjust the Paper's imageable height. The following is my code block for printing. I appreciate any help or direction you can point me to.

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
  pj.setJobName(" Print Component ");

  pj.setPrintable (new Printable() {    
    public int print(Graphics pg, PageFormat pf, int pageNum){
      if (pageNum > 0){
      return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
      }



      return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
  });
  if (pj.printDialog() == false)
  return;

  try {
        pj.print();
  } catch (PrinterException ex) {
        // handle exception
      System.out.println(ex);
  }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [validatePage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/PrinterJob.html#validatePage%28java.awt.print.PageFormat%29)

```
public abstract PageFormat validatePage(PageFormat page)
```

> Returns the clone of page with its settings adjusted to be compatible
>   with the current printer of this `PrinterJob`. For example, the
>   returned `PageFormat` could have its imageable area adjusted to fit
>   within the physical area of the paper that is used by the current
>   printer.
>
> Parameters: `page` - the `PageFormat` that is cloned and whose
>   settings are changed to be  compatible with the current printer
>
> Returns: a `PageFormat` that is cloned from page and whose settings
>   are changed to conform with this `PrinterJob`.

See also

- [“**PrinterException: Paper's imageable width is too small” I can see what's wrong, but how can I fix it?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601620/printerexception-papers-imageable-width-is-too-small-i-can-see-whats-wrong)

Comment: Thank you Alexey, you pointed in me in the right direction and I was able to print to the printer.