# Paper's imageable width is too small in java crstal report

Tags: java, printing, crystal-reports

We are using java Cristal report for printing.
We have a problem in printing from label printers.

it throws,

```
Caused by: com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.ReportSDKPrinterException: Report could not be printed.
at com.businessobjects.crystalreports.printer.bean.Printer.X(Unknown Source) ~[CrystalReportsRuntime-12.2.216.2042.jar:12.2.216.2042]
at com.businessobjects.crystalreports.printer.bean.ReportPrinter.print(Unknown Source) ~[CrystalReportsRuntime-12.2.216.2042.jar:12.2.216.2042]
at com.businessobjects.crystalreports.printer.bean.ReportPrinter.print(Unknown Source) ~[CrystalReportsRuntime-12.2.216.2042.jar:12.2.216.2042]
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.PrintOutputController.printReport(SourceFile:711) ~[CrystalReportsRuntime-12.2.216.2042.jar:12.2.216.2042]
... 161 common frames omitted
```

Caused by: java.awt.print.PrinterException: Paper's imageable width is too small.

this is the code use for printing

```
printerJob.printDialog();
reportClientDocument.getPrintOutputController().printReport(printerJob, null);
```

can any one know why this happens ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["PrinterException: Paper's imageable width is too small" I can see what's wrong, but how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601620/printerexception-papers-imageable-width-is-too-small-i-can-see-whats-wrong)

Comment: That solution not work for me.

Comment: I do not know is this java raster printing bug or not.Anyone knows please comment .